# dplyr::select of nested data frame

Tags: r, select, dplyr, purrr

I have the following example data frame:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(A = 1, B = 1)
df2 <- tibble(C = 2:4, D = 4:6)
df <- df %>%
        nest(B) %>%
        mutate(data = map(data, ~df2))
```

It's a nested `3x2` data frame (`df2`) in a `1x2` data frame (`df`). Is there a way to combine `purrr::map` and `dplyr::select` to select only `column C` in the nested data frame? **I'm hoping to avoid `unnest`.** The outcome should be:

```
      A             data
  <dbl>           <list>
1     1 <tibble [3 x 1]>
```

Comment: I may be unclear on what you want to do.  Does `mutate(data = map(data, ~select(df2, "C")))` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it's the right outcome, but your code uses `df2` and not `df`. I'd like a solution that uses `data` column of `df` only. I've provided a toy example, but in my actual case, it's easier if I try to select columns from within the nested data.frame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you've made the nested dataset that you have, you can use `select` in `map` on the "data" column in the same `mutate` call.

```
df %>%
    nest(B) %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~df2),
           data = map(data, ~select(.x, "C") ) )
```